# Create folder and insert file in Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a new folder in Drive and upload one (or more) files to that created folder. I use the code below, but the result is that both the folder and the file are placed in the root of my Drive.

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);

//create folder
$folder_mime = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
$folder_name = 'New Folder';

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$folder = new Google_DriveFile();

$folder->setTitle($folder_name);
$folder->setMimeType($folder_mime);
$service->files->insert($folder);

//upload file
$file_name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];
$file_mime = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"];
$file_path = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"];

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();

$file->setParents(array($folder_name));
$file->setTitle($file_name);
$file->setDescription('This is a '.$file_mime.' document');
$file->setMimeType($file_mime);
$service->files->insert(
    $file,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($file_path)
    )
);
```

Comment: I don't know PHP so can't correct your code, but the mistake you are making is to set the file's parent to the folder name. It should be set to the ID of the newly created folder which is returned by  insert($folder)

Comment: Ah amazing! That did it for me! Been worked up on this entire morning, I'll post the correct in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @pinoyyid, this is the code that works for me.

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);

//create folder
$folder_mime = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
$folder_name = 'New Folder';

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$folder = new Google_DriveFile();

$folder->setTitle($folder_name);
$folder->setMimeType($folder_mime);
$newFolder = $service->files->insert($folder);

$parentId  = $newFolder['id'];
//upload file
$file_name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];
$file_mime = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"];
$file_path = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"];

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();

if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
}

$file->setTitle($file_name);
$file->setDescription('This is a '.$file_mime.' document');
$file->setMimeType($file_mime);
try {
return $service->files->insert(
    $file,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($file_path)        
    )
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```